# Ionic beta 11 - Upgrade Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

So, Angular 2 has had it's final release. Now I want to upgrade to `angular-2.0.0` instead of `angular-2.0.0-rc4`. Since there have been some changes since RC4.

Now when I changed the `package.json` file and tried to `npm install`. I got a message saying

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.11 wants @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4
```

Is it already possible to upgrade to the final version of angular? Or should we keep waiting untill  Ionic releases a new beta version using the final angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ionic team has just upgraded Ionic 2 to be compatible with Angular 2 final.  See here:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-rc0

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to upgrade to the final version of `angular`, yes.
However, the team at Ionic haven't updated `ionic` to use the latest version of `angular` yet. As you can see, the version of `ionic` you have installed requires `angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4`.

I would wait until Ionic release a update that's compatible with the newest version of `angular` - because they depend heavily on `angular` functionality. Plus, if you wait for Ionic to release a new version that adopts the latest version of `angular`, it's guaranteed to be a stable release (you should very rarely use anything other than a stable release in a production environment).

misha130 points out in the comments the the next beta will include the newest angular.

Comment: Check out these milestones https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/milestones beta 12 will have latest angular and a bunch of other extra stutf